# Generating search term suggestions with Whoosh?

Tags: python, whoosh, search-suggestion

I've got a set of documents in a Whoosh index, and I want to provide a search term suggestion feature. So If you type "pop", some suggestions that could come up might be:

- popcorn
- popular
- pope
- Poplar Film
- pop culture

I've got the terms that should be coming up as suggestions going into an NGRAMWORDS field in my index, but when I do a query on that field I get autocompleted results rather than the expanded suggestions - so I get documents tagged with "pop culture", but no way to show that term to the user. 
(For comparison, I'd do this in ElasticSearch using a completion mapping on that field and then use the _suggest endpoint to get the suggestions.)

I can only find examples for autocomplete or spelling correction in the documentation or elsewhere on on the web. Is there any way I can get search term suggestions from my index with Whoosh?

**Edit:**
`expand_prefix` was a much-needed pointer in the right direction. I've ended up using a `KEYWORD(commas=True, lowercase=True)` for my suggest field, and code like this to get suggestions in most-common-first order (`expand_prefix` and `iter_prefix` will yield them in alphabetical order):

```
def get_suggestions(term):
    with ix.reader() as r:
        suggestions = [(s[0], s[1].doc_frequency()) for s in r.iter_prefix('suggest', term)]
    return sorted(suggestions, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not what you are looking for exactly, but probably can help you:

```
reader = index.reader()
for x in r.expand_prefix('title', 'pop'):
  print x
```

Output example:

```
pop
popcorn
popular
```

**Update**

Another workaround is to build another index with keywords as TEXT only. And play with search language. What I could achieve:

```
In [12]: list(ix.searcher().search(qp.parse('pop*')))
Out[12]: 
[<Hit {'keywords': u'popcorn'}>,
 <Hit {'keywords': u'popular'}>,
 <Hit {'keywords': u'pope'}>,
 <Hit {'keywords': u'Popular Film'}>,
 <Hit {'keywords': u'pop culture'}>]
```

Comment: Actually, that sounds very much like what I'm looking for! Just trying it out.

Comment: Hmm - the results I get back make it look like I shouldn't be using a NGRAMWORDS field type. If I use that on one of my KEYWORD fields it does exactly what I'd like.

Comment: Ok, so the problem with that is that it can't suggest multi-word terms. That seems like a function of the tokenizer. I don't understand why expand_prefix isn't working on KEYWORD fields. Is there an option I could pass to the field to enable it?

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the question with what I'm using.

Answer (score 5):

## Term Frequency Functions

I want to add to the answers here that there is actually a builtin function in whoosh that returns the top 'number' terms by term frequency. It is in the [whoosh docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.most_frequent_terms).

```
whoosh.reading.IndexReader.most_frequent_terms(fieldname, number=5, prefix='')
```

### tf-idf vs. frequency

Also, on the same page of the docs, right above the previous function in the [whoosh docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.most_distinctive_terms) is a function that returns the most *distinctive* terms rather than the most frequent. It uses the [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) score, which is effective at eliminating common but insignificant words like 'the'. This could be more or less useful depending on what you are looking for. it is appropriately named:

```
whoosh.reading.IndexReader.most_distinctive_terms(fieldname, number=5, prefix='')
```

Each of these would be used in this fashion:

```
with ix.reader() as r:
    print r.most_frequent_terms('suggestions', number=5, prefix='pop')
    print r.most_distinctive_terms('suggestions', number=5, prefix='pop')
```

## Multi-Word Suggestions

As well, I have had problems with multi-word suggestions. My solution was to create a schema in the following way:

```
fields.Schema(suggestions = fields.TEXT(),
              suggestion_phrases = fields.KEYWORD(commas=True, lowercase=True)
```

In the `suggestion_phrases` field, `commas=True` allows keywords to be stored with spaces and therefore have multiple words, and `lowercase=True` ignores capitalization (This can be removed if it is necessary to distinguish between capitalized and non-capitalized terms). Then, in order to get both single and multi-word suggestions, you would run either `most_frequent_terms()` or `most_distinctive_terms()` on both fields. Then combine the results.